# Show that the set $A$ contains an open interval.

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Let us consider the set $A=\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{5^k}: a_k=0,1,2,3,4\}$$,$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then show that the set $A$ contains an open interval.

My attempt: By the given set $A$, it is clear that $0$ belongs to it, if we consider all $a_k$ be $0$. Also if we take all $a_k$ to be $4$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{5^k}=1$. That is $1$ belongs to $A$. Also for every element $x$ in $A$, it is clear to see that $0≤ x≤ 1$. Then it is enough to show that $A=[0,1]$. Then we are done. But I am failed to show that $A=[0,1]$. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: For any real number $a \in [0,1]$, by dividing [0,1] to five equal parts you can choose a quinary number $a_1$ less than $a$ and $a_1+1/5$ is at least equal to $a$, then divide $[a_1,a_1+1/5]$ in the same way......you get a sequence which limit is $a$ at last...

Answer (score 2):

The set $A$ you have here is exactly the set of base 5 expansions of real numbers in $0 \leq x \leq 1$ (really it just is the set of all $0 \leq x \leq 1$, except  each $x$ is just written out in the series  form corresponding to its base 5 representation). Since every number in $[0, 1]$ has a base 5 expansion, $A  = [0, 1]$.

Comment: Is there any proof that any number from the interval $[0,1]$, can be expressed as base $5$ expansion $i.e.$ can be written as an element of $A$?

Comment: Yes; see https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-proof-that-every-real-number-has-a-decimal-base-ten-representation for instance, just replace 10 with any integer $\geq 2$. Or see other stackexchange posts about the topic.